# Why can't i clear FlexTable in UiBinder in GWTP?

Tags: gwt, gwtp, flextable

OK, I am using GWTP. I used eClipse to create TestPresenter.

In TestView.ui.xml, i have

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:FlexTable ui:field="messageFlexTable" borderWidth="1" /> </g:HTMLPanel>
```

In TestPresenter.java, i have

```
Button clearButton=new Button("Clear");
    getView().getComposeMessageHTMLPanel().add(clearButton);

    clearButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getView().getMessageFlexTable().clear();
        }

    });
```

But when clicking clear only buttons & labels inside that flextable got cleared, all the text & border of that flextable are still there?

However, If i  create FlexTable via code `FlexTable ft=new FlexTable();` then i have no problem?

What wrong? Is it a bug in GWTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FlexTable extends HTMLTable. As per javadoc for HTMLTable method clear()

> Removes all widgets from this table, but does not remove other HTML or text contents of cells.

If you really need to remove all table rows from it use `removeAllRows()` instead. See [HTMLTable#clear()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLTable.html#clear%28%29) and [FlexTable#removeAllRows()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlexTable.html#removeAllRows%28%29)

**Note:** for better performance you could also consider using [Grid](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Grid.html) instead if you do not need any particular features of FlexTable like dynamic size or colspan/rowspan.